# Sql Query select all rows not in another set

Tags: sql

Suppose I have this table:

```
sett_tb_plant_trans

(pk)uidplanttrans  field1  stoptime
---------------------------------   
x                  1       1/1/2000
y                  1       null 
z                  2       1/1/2000
k                  2       1/1/2000
v                  3       null
j                  4       null
```

I would like to select just `z` and `k` because them have the `stoptime` filled for all the rows and same "key" for the field1.

i did this query :

```
 select 
   field1 from sett_tb_plant_trans 
 where uidplanttrans not in 
   (select uidplanttrans from sett_tb_plant_trans where stoptime is null)
```

but returns some `field1`  that have some rows with `stoptime` null

why?

Comment: What? In your example the field "X" also has all the fields non-null. Perhaps you can explain better what you want.

Comment: ok i want just retrive z and k  because are the only rows that for the filed1 have the same key and have a stoptime filled! i dont want other rows because them have not fielled stoptime for all the values of the same value of filed1

Comment: then why did you accept an answer, when the accepted answer does not get the query results you just explained? I'm confused.. lol. a better query would be select * from sett_tb_plant_trans t1, sett_tb_plant_trans t2 where t1.field1=t2.field1 and t1.uidplanttrans != t2.uidplanttrans and t1.stoptime is not null ...

Comment: @KyleM the last query of Klaus is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simplify your query like this:

```
select field1 from sett_tb_plant_trans where stoptime is not null
```

It should definitely give the right results. There are however rows in your table where the same value for `field1` has a `stoptime` that is `null`, for example the rows with PK `x` and `y` have the same value `1` for `field1`, but for `y` stoptime is null.

If you only want those values of `field1` where there is no other row with the same `field1` value that has a `stoptime` that is null, you can do it with the sub-select approach, just slightly different:

```
 select 
 field1 from sett_tb_plant_trans 
 where field1 not in 
 (select field1 from sett_tb_plant_trans where stoptime is null)
```

This would give you 2 rows, because it is true for the rows with PK `z` and `k`. Depending on your needs you might want to select `distinct(field1) from ...`.

Comment: @frank, yes, I get it. So just use my second query. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why you are using a nested query.

Wouldn't

`select field1 from sett_tb_plant_trans where stoptime is not null`

work?